# package org.scalatest.testng does not exist (intellij)

Tags: intellij-idea, samtools

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5 on Linux and cannot compile htsjdk with the IDE. Perhaps someone has figured out how?

To be clear, htsjdk compiles just fine from the command line, just not in the IDE.

To compile, I click on the little recycle icon ("refresh external project") in the Gradle tab. After some work it gives me: "compilation completed with 8 errors".

The Build tab shows this error:

Error:(3, 28) java: package org.scalatest.testng does not exist

I haven't used Scala with IntelliJ before so I'm not sure how to proceed.